# C++ fstream in class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I started studying classes and now I faced a problem. I'm trying to put all my variables into a class, but I get errors:

```
main.cpp|6|error: expected identifier before string constant| 
main.cpp|6|error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant|
main.cpp|7|error: expected identifier before string constant|
main.cpp|7|error: expected ',' or '...' before string constant|
```

Although when I make them global everything works fine

```
    class Kauliukas{

        ifstream inFile("inFile.in");
        ofstream outFile("outFile.out");
        int n, akutes[100],k=0;

        void ivedimas();
        void skaiciavimas();
        void isvedimas();
};
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initialization goes in the constructor. That's different than, for instance, C#.
You must define a *constructor* like

```
class Kauliukas {
public:
    Kauliukas() : inFile("inFile.in"), outFile("outFile.out"), k(0) {}
private:
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    int n, akutes[100],k;

    void ivedimas();
    void skaiciavimas();
    void isvedimas();
};
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I've wanted :) Thank you

Comment: By the way, I read that making public variables in class is the worst, but how can I access private variables in my main and define them?

Comment: Note that in C++11, you can put initialization in the class definition, as long as the initialization expression is a constant expression.  http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#member-init

Comment: You must apply your judgement to design the public interface for your class. Data hiding require (in C++ more than, for instance, C#) more code, but guarantee better maintenance. If you remove the *private:* label you can access each variable from your main...

Answer (score 2):

In pre-C++11 versions of the language you can only declare variables inside the class body, you can't also initialize them (`ifstream inFile` is a declaration; `ifstream inFile("infile.in")` is a declaration and an initialization).

You have to do it like this:

```
class Kauliukas
{
  public:
    Kauliukas();

  private:
    ifstream inFile;
};

Kauliukas::Kauliukas()    // This is the constructor definition
    : inFile("infile.in") // This is called an initialization list
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: In standard C++ you **can** initialize members in the class definition. Check your copy of ISO 14882:2011. Whether compiler supports this standard is a different question.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I don't have a copy of the standard to check. Is the section you mentioned also part of pre-C++11 versions of the language?

Comment: Admittedly, the notation to initialize a member in a class either uses equal initialization (e.g. `std::ifstream in = std::ifstream("file");` which also requires the class to be copy or move constructible) or brace initialization (e.g. `std::ifstream in{"file"};`), i.e. using parenthesis doesn't work. The corresponding section is 9.2 [class.mem] paragraph 5 which is new in C++2011: this wasn't part of C++2003. To get recent drafts of the standard, you can go to [the committee's page](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/).